# What does where().eq("colName", new SelectArg()) mean?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

While running through some older code in our app, I ran into something like this:

```java
queryBuilder.selectRaw("myFirstColumnName");
queryBuilder.where().eq("mySecondColumnName", new SelectArg());
```

where `queryBuilder` is a `com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder`. Now, I have no idea how this maps to SQL, but I'm imagining this:

```sql
SELECT myFirstColumnName
WHERE mySecondColumnName = SELECT *
```

which I've never seen, nevermind used, before. **What is the purpose of this?** What could this be attempting to do, and what would the result be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queryBuilder.where()` method returns a `com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID>`.

The `eq()` method creates an equals comparison for the `where` conditional.

The resulting SQL query would be:
`SELECT myFirstColumnName WHERE mySecondColumnName = ?`

The `new SelectArg()` would be the value for the `?`.

Documentation reference for this:
http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html

Answer (score 4):

Good answer @novak.  Just to add some information:

```
queryBuilder.where().eq("mySecondColumnName", new SelectArg());
```

This is a bit of a strange pattern.  The typical usage of `SelectArg` is to create a variable so we can set the value later.  For example:

```
SelectArg arg = new SelectArg();
queryBuilder.where().eq("mySecondColumnName", arg);
...
arg.setValue("column1");
```

Sometimes we know the value of the argument up front but we still want to use the SQL `?` mechanism so we might do:

```
queryBuilder.where().eq("mySecondColumnName", new SelectArg("column1"));
```

We do this, for example, when we want to protect ourselves from [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or if we are using values that have SQL special characters (like quotes).